# How to have multiple object field types in record type inferred by function arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a function that infers the type of the object fields in a record given.

```
const exact = func({ foo: { a: 1, b: 2 } })
const _a: 1 = exact.foo.a
const _b: 2 = exact.foo.b // FIXME  typeof b is `number`, not `2`
```

I've been able to solve how to have `1` be inferred, but not `2`. How would this be achieved?

Here was where I got to so far:

```
type FIXME = number

interface Thing<a extends number, b extends number> {
  a: a
  b: b
}

// prettier-ignore
const x = <_ extends Record<keyof _, number>>(args: {[k in keyof _]: Thing<_[k],FIXME>}): {[k in keyof _]: Thing<_[k],FIXME>} => args
```

Here is a [TypeScript Playgrond](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgkgDQLIFEoF4oDsCuBbAIwgCcAoUgSy2BIDMBDAY2gBUALKgcwB56oIAHjSwATAM7Z8RYgBooBfkIiiJuQiQB8UAN6koUegC4De+cYKkAvuQD0NqGGIRgwCiQC0FTlgD2T0ow+WGLAUAIYUNwA+orC4lAAShCBxCLcANYQID60UFFyatIaGgAU9MScYsbaANrpUFRQmdm5UQC6xuxc0XVtMvDIKBqWAJTVdQ1YTVk5eR1QXVg8Ub39iKjDGFrlleSBwaGCTKGYAiXaULQ+PtUGxgCMcgTGAExQlu8jAUEheUZQ9wiR0YwAAdFcfKD6N8DnlnlA3phgWCIaCFHZYOs0FBQJBZgoKBIAAaFEhEgo+UJEl5E0hAA) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the easiest approach is to give `func` a [`const` generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters), as shown here:

```
function func<const T>(t: T) {
    return t;
}
```

By adding a `const` modifier to the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`, the compiler will try to infer the type of the `t` argument as if the caller had used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on it, thereby giving it the most specific type it can, including [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for literal values:

```
const exact = func({ foo: { a: 1, b: 2 } })
/* const exact: {
    readonly foo: {
        readonly a: 1;
        readonly b: 2;
    };
}*/

const _a: 1 = exact.foo.a // okay
const _b: 2 = exact.foo.b // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAeCCDOVEBUB8AFFAFx4CUiA3gFCL2IBOAplCI0lANw0C+NGMNkTMAHgENoiALzJwEQlWRw4ZJeLIBGADSIARmQBMiXifI0A9ACpEg4WMmlqdBi3EATBABsAnstXODEFMzB7efhqImjzBrqGeYL76RjEMvDy8VhY0Alg4APqRmjIiEtAAdMAq5eKIFhaIcADW4j65QgUGiMayDhVVcOV6dQ3NrTRAA)

Comment: Nice, I realized the same and came to the same conclusion. I still don't understand why its possible to infer for `a` and if that's an intended feature of TS...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing something like this -

```ts
type Cast<A, B> = A extends B ? A : B;

type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean;

type Narrow<A> = Cast<
  A,
  [] | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never) | { [K in keyof A]: Narrow<A[K]> }
>;


function x<T extends unknown, K extends Record<keyof K, Narrow<T>>,>(arg: K) { return arg; }

const result = x({ foo: { a: 1, b: 2 } });

const a = result.foo.a;
//    ^? const a: 1
const b = result.foo.b;
//    ^? const b: 2
const foo = result.foo;
//    ^? const foo: { a: 1; b: 2; }
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPByLN)

#### Why does this work?

This is essentially a trick that makes the Typescript compiler infer types as if we'd added an `as const` assertion with our input.

Whenever there's a constrained generic, that's used by another constrained generic, the Typescript compiler infers the type like `as const` or infers it literally, in other words.

You can see that in action, if you do something like this -

```ts
type Some = number | string;

function getValues<N extends Some, K extends Record<keyof K, N>>(arg: K) {
    return arg;
}

const value = getValues({ a: "something", b: "another thing" });
//    ^? const value: { a: "something"; b: “another thing”; }
```

This trick is what the `Narrow` (type utility used in the solution) makes use of. Which makes the deeply nested values inferred as literals here. As you can see that the `Cast` type utility, when used in `Narrow` does the same thing, that's being done in the `getValues` function code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand better the underlying behaviour of TS. I value that as there are so many different scenarios. An underlying knowledge is essential!

Comment: This method works for pre-v5 Typescript, where const generic parameter types aren't available as well. Ofcourse, you can use the const generic parameter if you're using v5, like @jcalz explained.